# Reformat a table in R by splitting a set of values in a column

Tags: r, csv, tidyr

How to reformat a table in `R` from:

| Fruit | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | US, UK |
| Pear | PL, DE, FR, AR |
| Banana | CO |

to:

| Fruit | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | US |
| Apple | UK |
| Pear | PL |
| Pear | DE |
| Pear | FR |
| Pear | AR |
| Banana | CO |

... assuming it comes in a file TSV file

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `tidyr::separate_rows(table, colname, separator)`.

A wrapper:

```r
STRINGdb.reformat.ann.table.per.gene <- function(path_of_tsv = '/Users/.../enrichment.DISEASES.tsv'
                                                 , column = 'matching proteins in your network (labels)'
                                                 , sep = ',') {
  
  annotation_tsv <- CodeAndRoll2::read.simple.tsv(path_of_tsv)
  stopifnot(column %in% colnames(annotation_tsv))
  (tbl_split <- tidyr::separate_rows(data = annotation_tsv, column, sep = sep ))
  CodeAndRoll2::write.simple.tsv(tbl_split, ManualName = ppp((path_of_tsv), "per.gene.tsv"))
  return(tbl_split)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a couple of ways to make it:

- Base R option using `stack`

```
with(df,  rev(stack(setNames(strsplit(Location, ", "), Fruit))))
```

- `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, .(Location = unlist(strsplit(Location, ", "))), Fruit]
```

- `tidyr` option using `unnest`

```
df %>%
  mutate(Location = strsplit(Location, ", ")) %>%
  unnest(Location)
```